# Error opening element of a php page with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a javascript that takes information from a url (song.php), that tells me the name of the song. But something is going wrong, because the javascript doesn't withdraw the required information.

Here is the element and javascript in order to facilitate help.

song.php:

```js
{"songinfo":"Christina Perri - A Thousand Years "}
```

Javascript

```js
<script> 
function executeQuery() {
  
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.radiojoven.6te.net/song.php',
    //url: '',
    success: function(data) {
      $( "#songinfo" ).text(data.songinfo);
    }
  });
  });
  setTimeout(executeQuery, 20000); // you could choose not to continue on failure...    
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  setTimeout(executeQuery, 3000);
});
</script>

<div id="songinfo" style="height:10px"></div>
```

Comment: this is due to `cors`. the php file will need to be configured to allow cross-origin requests

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your own API that bounces the data back like so:

```
<?php // song-api.php

$song  =  file_get_contents( 'http://www.radiojoven.6te.net/song.php' );

echo  $song;
exit();
```

---

And in the JavaScript, change the url as follows:

from:

```
url: 'http://www.radiojoven.6te.net/song.php',
```

to:

```
url: '/song-api.php',
```